# Persisting an array of images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

What's the best way to save and retrieve an array of images across app restarts?
I'm implementing a caching feature for offline viewing of downloaded images and just want to make sure I'm using the right persisting methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest & probably best solution would be to persist your images to disk, no question about it.

You could do something like this to save them as JPEG.

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
[data writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I'd like to save the entire array of images. Will this still work properly if I swap out the UIImage for an NSArray?

Comment: You would have to iterate through the array, converting each UIImage to its JPEG representation using something like the code that Yannick provided.

Comment: I undertand that, however, I should mention there will be multiple arrays that need to be cached separately. This way I could later just recreate them when the app launches. If I save the images, this may not work since they will all be save in the same directory and I won't know which set of images belong to which array.

Comment: Save your arrays in corresponding folders, you don't have to save them all in the same folder. iOS has 3 different "kinds" of folders: Documents, Temp & Cache. Have a look at the following [link](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/03/directories-temp-cache-documents/) that explains them, and store your images in a subfolder of the appropriate folder.

Comment: I'll take a look at your suggestions and see what works. Many Thanks.